# poor image quality after saving rotated bitmap to sdcard

Tags: android

I am making an app where in one of the activity i am fetching image from gallery and showing it in adapter like image below

[image]

I have to rotate that image and save it to sdcard. My code is doing fine but after saving it to sdcard i get very poor quality of image. my code is:

```
 viewHolder.imgViewRotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            imagePosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);

            Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uriList.get(rotatePosition).toString()));
                rotated.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Any suggestions will be great help.

Comment: try reducing the compression ratio 100 to 50

Comment: still getting distorted image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize a bitmap eficiently and with out losing quality in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327846/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-eficiently-and-with-out-losing-quality-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize the image using `BitmapFactory` `inSampleSize` option and the image doesn't lose quality at all. Code:

```
          BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
              Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempDir+"/"+photo1_path , bmpFactoryOptions);

              int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)600);
              int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)800);

              if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
              {
               if (heightRatio > widthRatio){
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
               } else {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
               } 
              }

              bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
              bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempDir+"/"+photo1_path, bmpFactoryOptions);
             
              // recreate the new Bitmap
        src = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0,bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Comment: i dont have to reduce the size of image i have to just rotate it and save the rotated bitmap to sdcard

Comment: Then you are misleading others by your question title.

Comment: it worked a bit but still image got little distorted.

Comment: The problem with `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` is that the file will get bigger every time it is rotated.