# How to rotate image without reducing its quality?

Tags: android, image

I want to load an image from camera folder, but image has different orientation (rotated).
So I rotate it. When I create new file to save rotated image, the quality of that image is reduced.

I tried create new file from origin file without rotating it,
but quality image still reduced.

I think that image quality gets reduced when save image.

**Issue:** Rotating an image reduces image quality.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In what format do you save these images??

Comment: No. Rotating does not have impact on quality. You do something wrong.

Comment: And copying a file will not reduce quality too. You do it wrong.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696489/poor-image-quality-after-saving-rotated-bitmap-to-sdcard

Comment: @jackjay Origin image have format .jpg and I saved it with format .jpg

Comment: @greenapps I get bitmap from image, after I rotate image and get uri image and final I create new file to save uri.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. It looks as if you dont want help.

Comment: @greenapps, I think that it happen error when I get bitmap and save it into new file. and copy will does not reduce quality image. It's right

Comment: Try saving it in `.png` format. Other formats are compressed formats while `.png` is raw format to save image files.

Comment: @jackjay I check extension of image, and extension of new image depend on extension of origin image. If you have source about it, please attach here.

Comment: @LongHoang no source is required. When you are saving your image, you must be giving some other name like `xyzimage.jpg`, just change it to `xyzimage.png`.

Comment: I've generated name from timestamp, I make sure that name hasn't duplicate