# Downloaded images are not displayed on android devices with high resolution

Tags: android, image, download, drawable

Downloaded images are not displayed on devices with  resolution higher than 1280x720. I tried different DPI of images.  How to resolve this? Thanks in advance. I use such code:

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtUrl;
private ImageView imgView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Веб-адрес картинки
    String url = "http://somesite.com/images/picture.jpg";
    txtUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    txtUrl.setText(url);

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    try {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(url));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        txtUrl.setText("Error: Exception");
    }
}

private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    return Drawable.createFromStream(
            (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a OutOfMemory error.
You have to resize image.
Convert drawable to Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)grabImageFromUrl(url)).getBitmap();
```

and resize using this solution:

[Resizing a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341243/2183365)