# ImageView not displaying some images

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to display an image in *Android*'s *ImageView* , but for an unknown reason some images are not displayed. The images that are working are relatively small and the ones not working are larger (1280x720) or so. I even tried to limit the image's size, by adding maxWidth or maxHeight in .xml file or even by code, but still no result.

Here's my .xml code for ImageView;

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/test3" />
```

And for my code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageImageView);
        imageView.requestLayout();
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Any ideas / suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: Not working how? Add android:scaleType="centerInside" and see if they're displayed.

Comment: Not working as nothing is displayed  when I try to insert larger images. I will add that line and see what happens.

Comment: Nope, still not displaying.

Comment: and what happens if you remove the maxHeight and maxWidth attributes from your ImageView? does it work?

Comment: No, it was the initial try. I only added  this lines in hoping it will fix the issue, but no success.

Comment: are you getting out of memory exceptions or similar or is it just simply blank? This is very strange. Please paste your entire layout that includes the imageview.

Comment: For extra large images 2560x1600 or larger yes. But for my image, which is 1280x720, i don't get the out of memory exception. The entire layout is composed only from the default LinearLayout and the imageView above.

Comment: i think you are suffering from memory issues. Try to re-size the image. You can use this code_ [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327846/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-eficiently-and-with-out-losing-quality-in-android/8341243#8341243]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try resizing your image like :

```
private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
            (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * 0.5), (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * 0.5), false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
}
```

And in your onCreateView() of your fragment:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageImageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
        Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test3);
        draw = resize(draw);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

Comment: I have the same problem and tried the above solution but it crashes on the setImageResource(0) with null resource exception. I then commented out this line and tried again. It crashed again with error "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable".

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had an ImageView which would display perfectly anywhere in my app apart from inside a Fragment. Annoying that this is necessary, can anyone explain why it's needed?

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem sometime ago, my solution was checking the image **naming convention** example(*"-" to "_",no space within names, ...*) you can check the java naming convention for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Add these two lines in xml code of your image view:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageImageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:src="@drawable/test3" />
```

Try this :)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i have already tried this method and no success.

Answer (score 0):

For me i was getting this error

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2250x4386, max=4096x4096)
```

my image size was actually 750x1462 but because it was sitting in the drawable-mdpi res bucket i think behind the scenes it was being scaled up, so i moved it to xxhdpi and then it loaded the image without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might have come a little late. I think the filename could also be a problem. I just renamed mine from **sebastian-staines-mfzdRsWsiRA-unsplash.jpg** to **sebastian_staines.jpg** in my drawable folder in Android Studio and Boom, The Imageview Displayed it.
Hope this helps someone else

Comment: This answer is only applicable to your specific use case, hence not generally acceptable