# Android image scale quality

Tags: android, image

I’ve looked through a lot of questions regarding image quality and tried a bunch of them, but I can’t seem to find a solution to this issue. I am trying to scale an image down from my phone gallery and, while it resizes to the correct dimensions, the image quality drops. Take a look at this image that I scaled down by hand in Apple Preview:

[image]

vs what my function is doing

[image]

Here’s my function below. My intention with this function was to scale the image down proportionally to as close to the desired width as I can get:

```
public static Bitmap resize(String filepath, float desired_width)
{
    float percent = getPercent(filepath, desired_width);
    int newWidth = Math.round(getImageWidth(filepath) * percent);
    int newHeight = Math.round(getImageHeight(filepath) * percent);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
    return bmp;

}
```

I’ve tried removing the “options”  argument decodeFile, but the image looks the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true)`?

Comment: check answer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327846/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-eficiently-and-with-out-losing-quality-in-android

Comment: @FabinPaul, I tried that. Same result. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: check if this answer works out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap#answer-7468636)